App not opening action button from the Android 13 device React native push notificaions
I'm getting this error while clicking on the action button from the Android 13 device "Indirect notification activity start (trampoline) from com.xxx blocked"
startActivity method is not working properly for Android 13 and above versions, I'm using "react-native-push-notification": "8.1.1" version with targetSdkVersion 33
I have also changed these two lines in node_modules/react-native-push-notification/android/build.gradle as per this #2352 but its not working for action button click(app is not launching)

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${safeExtGet('firebaseMessagingVersion', '21.1.0')}"


implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${safeExtGet('firebaseMessagingVersion', '23.3.1')}"
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:21.1.0"

